# query inside a while loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, while-loop

are/is there any problem with this code?

```
while($qtytoAdd > 0) {
    if(($remBalance - $qtytoAdd) >= 0) {
        mysql_query('UPDATE `estimates` SET `qty_rec` = `qty_rec` + "'.$qtytoAdd.'" WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).'" AND `est_id` = "'.$balid.'"');
        mysql_query('UPDATE `requestdetails` SET `current_rec_qty` = `current_rec_qty` + "'.$qtytoAdd.'" WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).'" AND `req_id` = "'.$currid.'"');
    } else {
        mysql_query('UPDATE `estimates` SET `qty_rec` = "'.$remBalance.'" + "'.$currRec.'" WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).'" AND `est_id` = "'.$balid.'"');
        mysql_query('UPDATE `requestdetails` SET `current_rec_qty` = "'.$remBalance.'" + "'.$currRec.'" WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).'" AND `req_id` = "'.$currid.'"');
        $qtytoAdd = $qtytoAdd - $remBalance;
    }
    return $qtytoAdd;
}
```

Both conditions seems to be working but the part where I'll assign the new values for `$qtytoAdd` is not. And do I need to use the return function to let it continue looping. I'm a newbie. Please help.

```
foreach($mat_desc as $mat_key => $materials){
    $qtytoAdd = $rec_qty[$mat_key];
    $remBalance = mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT `est_qty` - `qty_rec` as balance FROM `estimates` WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).'" AND `qty_rec` <> `est_qty` ORDER BY `item_id` ASC'), 0);
    $balid = mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT `est_id` FROM `estimates` WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).'" AND `qty_rec` <> `est_qty` ORDER BY `item_id` ASC'), 0);
    $currRec = mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT `qty_rec` FROM `estimates` WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).'" AND `qty_rec` <> `est_qty`'), 0);
    $currid = mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT `req_id` FROM `requestdetails` JOIN `request` USING(`req_id`) WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).'" AND `req_qty` <> `current_rec_qty` ORDER BY `req_id` ASC'), 0);

    mysql_query('INSERT INTO `receivedetails` (`rec_id`,`mat_id`,`rec_qty`) VALUES ('.$rec_id.','.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).','.$qtytoAdd.')');

    while($qtytoAdd > 0) {
        if(($remBalance - $qtytoAdd) >= 0) {
            mysql_query('UPDATE `estimates` SET `qty_rec` = `qty_rec` + "'.$qtytoAdd.'" WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).'" AND `est_id` = "'.$balid.'"');
            mysql_query('UPDATE `requestdetails` SET `current_rec_qty` = `current_rec_qty` + "'.$qtytoAdd.'" WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).'" AND `req_id` = "'.$currid.'"');
            $qtytoAdd = 0;
        } else {
            mysql_query('UPDATE `estimates` SET `qty_rec` = "'.$remBalance.'" + "'.$currRec.'" WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).'" AND `est_id` = "'.$balid.'"');
            mysql_query('UPDATE `requestdetails` SET `current_rec_qty` = "'.$remBalance.'" + "'.$currRec.'" WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).'" AND `req_id` = "'.$currid.'"');
            $qtytoAdd = $qtytoAdd - $remBalance;
        }
    }

    mysql_query('UPDATE `estimates` SET `qty_onhand` = `qty_rec` - `qty_rel` WHERE `proj_id` = '.$proj_id.' AND `qty_rec` <> `est_qty` AND `mat_id` = '.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).' AND `est_id` = '.$balid.'');
}
```

This is actually the whole code. :]

Comment: `return` will end whatever function you're in - it's not used for controlling loops.  What is the rest of the function this loop is part of?

Comment: Cue the stock comment to AVOID `mysql_query` .... it is deprecated

Comment: @Crontab but whenever I remove the `return` the table that I'm updating is getting messed up.

Comment: Your code can gain legibility and portability by setting up the SQL as string variables.  `$SQL_1 = "Update ... "`

Comment: Like I asked, what is the rest of the surrounding code?  It's near impossible to give you an appropriate answer with only a small snippet of code.  Maybe `return` *is* appropriate, maybe `break` is.  Maybe you need to change the condition of your `while` statement.

Comment: I agree with Crontab ... that said, I just have to wonder if the return line should be down at the bottom, OUTSIDE the while loop.

Comment: @Crontab, I edited the code and included the whole code. :]

Comment: Well, the new code is different but makes more sense.  Putting multiple MySQL updates into a while loop isn't very efficient though.  Consider using PHP variables to calculate what needs to be updated and then doing the actual database updates *after* the loop.

Answer (score 1):

> do I need to use the return function to let it continue looping

You don't need a return to continue to loop. You use [return](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) when you want to return from the current function and go back.

> If called from within a function, the return statement immediately
>   ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as
>   the value of the function call. return will also end the execution of
>   an eval() statement or script file.

PHP & Query

```
while($qtytoAdd > 0) {
    if(($remBalance - $qtytoAdd) >= 0) {
        mysql_query('UPDATE `estimates` SET `qty_rec` = `qty_rec` + "'.$qtytoAdd.'" WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).'" AND `est_id` = "'.$balid.'"');
        mysql_query('UPDATE `requestdetails` SET `current_rec_qty` = `current_rec_qty` + "'.$qtytoAdd.'" WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).'" AND `req_id` = "'.$currid.'"');
        $qtytoAdd = $qtytoAdd - $remBalance; // this part does not exist in your code.
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-------- depends on your requirement. I added the same line.  
 } else {
        mysql_query('UPDATE `estimates` SET `qty_rec` = "'.$remBalance.'" + "'.$currRec.'" WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).'" AND `est_id` = "'.$balid.'"');
        mysql_query('UPDATE `requestdetails` SET `current_rec_qty` = "'.$remBalance.'" + "'.$currRec.'" WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).'" AND `req_id` = "'.$currid.'"');
        $qtytoAdd = $qtytoAdd - $remBalance;
    }
}
```

Where you have gone wrong

According to your code if the 1st if is true you don't make changes to the $qtytoAdd. Plus you return from the function. So the while loop will be executed only once.

Comment: If the `$qtytoAdd` reassignment lines are the same, it should be placed outside of the conditional inside the `while` (instead of duplicated in both blocks of the conditional).